# npx tsc has no output\does nothing

Tags: typescript

I am trying a basic ts setup to use top-level await and it works (prints the result from the api) if I run `tsc && node dist/main.js`, but when I run `npx tsc` - it does nothing but generate `dist` folder with main.js and main.js.map.
I am trying to understand why npx tsc doesn't work and what I am doing wrong.

Here is my setup

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "module": "es2022",
    "target": "ES2021",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**src/main.ts**

````
import axios from "axios"

let api = 'https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity'
let response = await axios.get(api)

console.log(`You could ${response.data.activity}`)
```
````

Comment: Could not replicate, I get `main.js` and `main.d.ts` in `dist/`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, it does generate main.js and main.js.map. 
I was following instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71526250/12447423) and from what I understood the code in `main.ts` should be executed as well.

Comment: You have misunderstood, `tsc` just transpiles TypeScript to JavaScript, `tsc && node dist/main.js`, which you already know works, would be compile _then run_.

Answer (score 1):

`npx tsc` and `tsc` should both accomplish the same thing. The only difference is which version of `tsc` they use.

- `npx tsc` will use the local version of `tsc` in your node_modules if it is available
- `tsc` uses the global `tsc` installed with TypeScript

---

If you found this question because your `npx tsc` command was not producing any output, make sure that "[noEmit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmit)" is set to `false` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score -2):

The tsc command's purpose is to transpile typescript to javascript, just run `tsc && node dist/main.js` to transpile and then have node start the main.js file in the `dist` folder.

Comment: maybe explain how to run it then?

Comment: How to run what exactly?

Comment: i must have misread your comment the first time in relation to the question. answer is fine. if you want to make a slight edit i can revote.

Comment: What might that edit be? I welcome every opportunity to learn