# Unable to use await expressions

Tags: typescript

Even though my `tsconfig.json` is inline with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71526250/17333696).

I still get this error:

`Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.`

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

As you can see the `target` is set to `es2017`, `module` is set to `esnext`.

Here is the where the error is occuring:

```js
await Promise.all(new Array(10).fill(1).map((_,i) => {
    return prisma.playlist.create({
        data: {
            name: `Playlist #${i+1}`,
            user: {
                connect: {id: user.id},
            },
            songs: {
                connect: songs.map((song) => ({
                    id: song.id,

                }))
            }
        },
    })})
)
```

At the `await` statement. I restarted my IDE and tried using `es2022` and `es5` as targets, but no success.

Comment: `top-level` await only works in ecmascript modules. Make sure yours is one. See this [link](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await)