# How to prevent TypeScript from transpiling classes to ES5?

Tags: typescript

I have code like this:

```js
import { SuperClass } from 'some-library';

export class MyClass extends SuperClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

The program fails with an error like this:

```
        var _this = _super.call(this)) || this;
                           ^

TypeError: Class constructor SuperClass cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50203532), this problem is caused by the fact that TypeScript transpiles classes to ES5, while SuperClass is an ES6 class.

The referenced answer says setting TypeScript's "target" option to es6 should fix it. However, if I do this then TypeScript still outputs ES5 classes. Setting 'target' to 'es2018' or '2020' doesn't help either. No matter what I do, the output looks like this:

```js
var MyClass = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(MyClass, _super);
    function MyClass() {
```

This is my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2018",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["es2018"],
        "composite": true
    },
    "include": ["*.ts"]
}
```

How can I make TypeScript output ES6 classes?

Comment: Maybe  `TypeScript transpiles classes to ES5` is not the issue. There could be something wrong with your `SuperClass` itself

Comment: @Ambujsahu I checked the SuperClass's source and it's indeed an ES6 class.

Comment: How are you using MyClass ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that target=es6 *does* work, and that the problem was actually that I ran `tsc myfile.ts` instead of `tsc` (without parameters). When a file is passed as a parameter then tsc [ignores tsconfig.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39412786/20816), which is why the "target" option in my tsconfig.json had no effect. If I pass `--target=es6` as a CLI parameter then TypeScript properly transpiles my class to an ES6 class.